# Cannot control state with a trigger

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine, raycasting

Ok, Ive been at this for hours. Ive looked all over Unity forums and don't know why this is happening. I can't get my animation controller to properly switch between an animation and a blank idle state on a trigger,

I need to trigger a single animation, a walk animation step, from an idle state every time the screen is tapped thus the person moves 1 square. I have an Inputmanager that handles my taps, and Ive connected my idle and animation states with transitions both set to the trigger.

[image]

I call the trigger every time I get a tap, and this works great the FIRST time, meaning the animation runs through entirely then goes to idle:

```
if(Input.touches.Length > 0 ){
            Touch t = Input.GetTouch (0);
if(t.phase == TouchPhase.Ended){

if (objectDetected == false) {
                    //print ("tap");
                    animator.SetTrigger ("oneStep");
                    return swipes.tap;

                }

                objectDetected = false;
//tap should be done
            }

            return swipes.none;
        }
```

My problem is this only works every OTHER time, meaning the first, third, fifth and so on. On these taps the animator looks like this as it should - it runs through the walk animation ONCE then stops:

[image]

The 2nd, fourth, and every other time, however, something happens that makes it go straight to idle. I really don't know what is occurring, but this is the animator:

[image]

Ive tried everything - disabling exit time, enabling exit time, Resetting the trigger at the very end of the tap phase ending and like this on timer:

```
IEnumerator waitForAnim(float wait) {

        yield return new WaitForSeconds (wait);
        //animator.SetTrigger ("backToIdle");
        animator.ResetTrigger("oneStep");
        print ("FINISHED!!!!");

    }
```

then

```
if (objectDetected == false) {
                    //print ("tap");

                    animator.SetTrigger ("oneStep");
                    StartCoroutine(waitForAnim(0.5f));

                    return swipes.tap;

                }
```

Im desperate with this. How can I just trigger the animation to play once, then go to idle, every time I get a tap? Whats wrong?

Both transitions:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the transition between the walk2 state and the Idle state ?

Comment: Sure, look at the edit

Comment: I think it's really obvious : If you want the walk animation to automatically reset to the idle state, then, remove the condition of the transition walk2 → Idle test with the trigger `oneStep`

Comment: Well you're amazing. Thank you. Obvious